# How to reload or refresh store data of one page on event of another page

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I have two js files in my application, both are open in tabs.
I use first js file to insert data (add data to table).
And second file for showing records in grid.
I want to refresh store of second page on save event of first page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used following code after performing insert and delete operations to reload data in my grid, and it works.

```
Ext.getCmp('myGridID').store.reload();
```

Answer (score 3):

try using

```
Ext.getStore('storeId').reload();
```

where storeId is the Store id of the store that needs to be reloaded.

Answer (score 1):

I used this: `Ext.getCmp('#idofgrid').getView().refresh();` when the store of #idofgrid has new data.

Try to add that line into save event of the first page and replace #idofgrid with the id of the second grid.

Comment: Thank you @Carlos, I tried with this code, but it's not working